# how to disable screen capture in flutter programming language?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, screenshot, disable

In this case I will disable the screen capture on certain pages. which contains documents that are vulnerable to misuse. Does Flutter support that?

this code main.dart:

```
  Future<void> _toggleScreenShot() async {

    if (_isSecureScreen == true) {
      await FlutterWindowManager
          .addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
      print("Tidak bisa ");
    } else {
      await FlutterWindowManager
          .clearFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
      print("Tidak bisa ");
    }

    setState(() {
      _isSecureScreen = !_isSecureScreen;
    });
  }
```

this code mainactivity.kt :

```
@Override
fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this package [flutter_windowmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager)

In our App, we only wished to disable screenshots for specific screens, rather than across the entire application lifecycle. This can now be accomplished by simply calling:

```
await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
```

for the relevant screen.

Add this to your dependencies in pubspec.yaml

```
flutter_windowmanager: ^0.0.2
```

Comment: I've used these depedencies. but it doesn't work. @Android_id

Comment: Please paste your code of what have you tried

Comment: '  Future<void> _toggleScreenShot() async {

    if (_isSecureScreen == true) {
      await FlutterWindowManager
          .addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
      print("Tidak bisa ");
    } else {
      await FlutterWindowManager
          .clearFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
      print("Tidak bisa ");
    }

    setState(() {
      _isSecureScreen = !_isSecureScreen;
    });
  }'